# Using static get only property thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have this class:

```
class MyFoo
{
    private static readonly string _foo = InitFoo();

    public static string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return _foo;
        }
    }

    private static string InitFoo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("InitFoo"); 
        // do some job
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

The private static `_foo` member is initialized only once when there is a reference to `MyFoo.Foo`.

The data returned from `InitFoo()` is large and the method might be time consuming (a matter of 1-2 seconds max), My question, is there a chance that while a thread is referencing `MyFoo.Foo` another thread that reference it will get an uncompleted or un-initialized data back b/c the `InitFoo()` is not complete yet?

In other words, Is the above thread-safe? if not how to make it thread-safe (if possible avoid a lock object?)

Thanks.

---

EDIT: following the comments about `Lazy<T>` is it now better for thread safety?:

```
public sealed class MyFoo
{
    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit        
    static MyFoo() { }

    private static readonly Lazy<string> _foo = InitFoo();

    public static string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return _foo.Value;
        }
    }

    private static Lazy<string> InitFoo()
    {
        string s = "Foo";
        return new Lazy<string>(() => s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Lazy<T>`, should be guaranteed to be thread safe then.

Comment: @maccettura, How would I change the above to use `Lazy<T>`? Should i use it on the static member or what?

Comment: Jon Skeet has a nice blurb about [thread safe singletons in C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy).  You should be able to just pull from there

Comment: @elgonzo, you say its safe but also: `"but for peace of mind..." `, so the code above is thread safe or not?

Comment: @maccettura, But I don't want a singleton class instance. I am using the class as static. Can you please show an example of how to turn a above to use Lazy<T>?

Comment: For all intents and purposes your `_foo` / `Foo` property _is_ a singleton.  They are read-only, static members of a class which means it will be shared among all instances and a new instance could never be created.  Your issue is that it is not currently thread safe, so if you look at the link I posted you can make it thread safe

Comment: @maccettura You linked an article that *specifically explains that the code the OP is using is safe*.  Also no, a static field is not at all a singleton.  A singleton is a class that there can only ever be one instance of.  A static property is just a property that's shared among all instances.  You can use the latter as one tool in accomplishing the former, but that doesn't make all static fields inherently singletons.

Comment: @maccettura, Is that how to do it in my case? https://pastebin.com/JCDCzGPZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a chance that while a thread is referencing MyFoo.Foo another thread that reference it will get an uncompleted or un-initialized data back b/c the InitFoo() is not complete yet?

No. Type initialization is thread-safe:

- No other threads get to use your type while it's being initialized by another thread
- All writes to memory performed by the initialization thread are made visible to other threads when the initialization has been performed

There's one wrinkle which is that if the *same* thread that's initializing `MyFoo` ends up reading `MyFoo._foo` before it's finished initializing, that will cause a problem. That can be particularly awkward to diagnose if there are types that depend on each other for initialization in a cycle.

Here's an example, with two type initializers that each use a value from the other. They both have static constructors to make the behavior deterministic. (The rules for when types are initialized depend on whether or not they have static constructors.)

```
using System;

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Determine which type to initialize first based on whether there
        // are any command line arguemnts.
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            Class2.DoNothing();
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Class1.Value1: {Class1.Value1}"); 
        Console.WriteLine($"Class2.Value2: {Class2.Value2}"); 
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public static readonly string Value1 =
        $"When initializing Class1.Value1, Class2.Value2={Class2.Value2}";

    static Class1() {}
}

public class Class2
{
    public static readonly string Value2 =
        $"When initializing Class2.Value2, Class2.Value2={Class1.Value1}";

    static Class2() {}

    public static void DoNothing() {}
}
```

Running this without any command line arguments, `Class1` starts initializing first, which in turn initializes `Class2`:

```
Class1.Value1: When initializing Class1.Value1, Class2.Value2=When initializing Class2.Value2, Class2.Value2=
Class2.Value2: When initializing Class2.Value2, Class2.Value2=
```

With any command line argument, we initialize `Class2` first, which in turn initializes `Class1`:

```
Class1.Value1: When initializing Class1.Value1, Class2.Value2=
Class2.Value2: When initializing Class2.Value2, Class2.Value2=When initializing Class1.Value1, Class2.Value2=
```

Comment: Wow, How can one avoid this behavior?

Comment: @zig: Be careful what you do in static initializers, basically :)

Comment: So, is my code thread-safe or not? Can you also look at my edit please?

Comment: @zig: You don't need `Lazy<T>` here, no. You're not trying to delay anything. It's already safe.

Comment: Do I need to add the `static MyFoo() { }` ?. I'm not sure I understand what its for...

Comment: @zig: You only need it if you want to make sure the type initializer is called *exactly* the first time the type is used. In most cases you won't care - I only included it here because the timing is really important for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Now the issue is more clear to me specially after I read this: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx